# What is the status of "Notes" in ICAO Annexes?

Tags: icao-sarps

As per the forward to ICAO Annex 11, the status of a "NOTE" in any annex is - **"Notes included in the text, where appropriate, to give factual information or references bearing on the Standards or Recommended Practices in question, but not constituting part of the Standards or Recommended Practices."**
So, does it mean, a note given in the Annex does not hold any authority as it is not a part of the SARPs ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But there should not be a contradiction to the standard. Additional material usually serves to guide the user of the standard.